# Have to put files in static_dir but need to read them afterwards

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, jinja2

I just started using google app engine. In order to use templates, I'm using jinja2.
I want to add images dynamically after I set the width and height of the img tag. I used
PIL in order to read the image size and put the one I want.

However when I open the image with PIL, I need it not to be in a static_dir 
and to put the image in the img tag, I need it to be in the static_dir.

As a testing solution I've copied the folder to see if I get results and I did. But as 
you can see having each image saved twice is kind of bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the file to be both static (served fast by not having to pass through your app) and available to the app, note the `application_reabable` option in the description of [static file handler patterns](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers). It does want you want without you having to duplicate files.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. I should look more into those options.